# What is NSRunLoop?

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, nsrunloop

I have been reading some documents about run loop, but still can not understand it exactly.
  As iOS is not open source, while `NSRunLoop` is special for iOS/Mac OS X platform, what is its real implementation inside?

Comment: From here you can get more idea... http://etutorials.org/Programming/Cocoa/Part+II+API+Quick+Reference/Chapter+13.+Foundation+Classes/NSRunLoop/

Answer (score 0):

If you have some kind of user interface, or other code that needs to listen to events (like network ports), you need a run loop. Every NSThread automatically gets its own run loop, and you very rarely have to concern yourself with them directly. The run loop is also in charge of creating and releasing autorelease pools.

For more information :
[What is the basic difference between NSTimer, NSTask, NSThread and NSRunloop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124207/what-is-the-basic-difference-between-nstimer-nstask-nsthread-and-nsrunloop)